# MacOS issues with installing Haskell with HomeBrew

Tags: haskell, homebrew

If I enter the following:
`brew install haskell-stack`

I get:
`Warning: haskell-stack 2.9.1 is already installed and up-to-date.`

So the stack should be installed

then I enter this: `brew install ghc`

and then comes:

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ghc/manifests/9.2.4

######################################################################## 100.0%

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ghc/blobs/sha256:9958adc0fe9861

==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sh

######################################################################## 100.0%

==> Pouring ghc--9.2.4.monterey.bottle.tar.gz

==> /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/9.2.4/bin/ghc-pkg recache

==> Caveats

Bash completion has been installed to:

 /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

==> Summary

 /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/9.2.4: 7,752 files, 1.5GB

==> Running `brew cleanup ghc`...

Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.

Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

What now? When I type ghc after this nothing happens, so this should not be installed yet.

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing happens"? Is there some kind of error message or does it literally do nothing at all? If it is not installed then it should at least say something like `command not found: ghc`.

Comment: This is what I get:                                                                                                      ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.

Comment: That sounds like what you see when you've given the compiler no input source to compile. I think you wanted GHCi instead.

Comment: You will also want an editor - if you haven't a preference already get Visual Studio Code, and then install the extension 'Haskell' so that you get HLS (Haskell Language Server) support.

Comment: After installing visual studio code and adding haskell it works, thanks (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install Visual Studio Code and adding Haskell from it.

Comment: You answer would be better to posted as a comment rather than a post.